# Select pairs as single rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a log table like this in mysql:

```
id | pair | checkintime         | checkouttime        | comment 
1  |    1 | 2016-05-28 08:10:22 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | bla bla1
2  |    1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2016-05-28 11:10:22 | bla bla2
3  |    3 | 2016-05-29 06:12:12 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | bla bla3
4  |    3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2016-05-29 09:02:22 | bla bla4
5  |    5 | 2016-05-23 08:32:24 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | bla bla5
```

Both checkin and checkout actions generates a single row with an unique id in db. Now I want to make a SELECT-query and get a result with each pair on a single row:

```
ci_id | ci_time             | ci_comment | co_id | co_time             | co_comment  | 
1     | 2016-05-28 08:10:22 | bla bla2   | 2     | 2016-05-28 11:10:22 | bla bla1    |
3     | 2016-05-29 06:12:12 | bla bla3   | 4     | 2016-05-29 09:02:22 | bla bla4    |
5     | 2016-05-23 08:32:24 | bla bla5   |       |                     |             |
```

Note it's possible that the checkout row is not present (like id 5 that has not any related pair row)

Someone who can help me with the SQL query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to self join the log table on itself using the `pair` column and use the datetime fields to determine which is check in and which is check out.:

```
select l1.id as ci_id, l1.comment as ci_comment, ..., l2.id as co_id, l2.comment as co_comment, ...
from log l1
left join log l2 on l1.pair=l2.pair and l2.checkintime='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
where l1.checkouttime='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that a logout event (and thus a row in the log table) can only be created *after* the login-event and that therefore the id of the logout-row must be greater than the login-row one can use following query:

```
SELECT
  l1.id AS ci_id,
  l1.checkintime AS ci_time,
  l1.comment AS ci_comment,
  l2.id AS co_id,
  l2.checkouttime AS co_time,
  l2.comment AS co_comment
FROM
  log_table l1 LEFT JOIN log_table l2 ON (l1.pair = l2.pair AND l1.id < l2.id)
```

If there is no checkout row the co_* columns will be shown as NULL values, if you need to display an empty cell you should add `IFNULL(l2.id AS co_id, "")` etc to the select-clause as needed.